# Set a maximum length, requirement for space and minimum characters

Tags: regex

I have a very specific requirement for a check (on a name field) but don't know how to produce the required regex.

The requirements are as follows:

- The string **must** be no longer than 35 characters
- The string will allow upper and lower case characters, hyphen and apostrophe
- The string **must** include 2 (space separated) words of at least 2 characters
- The two words can be any length provided the following are met:

  - Both words are at least 2 characters
  - A space character is included between words
  - The total of all characters (including the space character) cannot be more than 35 characters

Based on this, the following strings should get the defined results:

**Success**:

```
Bartholomew Jamieson-Smithson-West
Mellisa Wu
Li Smith
```

**Fail**

```
Andy Bartholomew-Jamieson-Smithson-West
L Bartholomew-Jamieson-Smithson-Wu
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using the following regex:

```
/^(?!.{36,})[a-z'-]{2,}\s[a-z'-]{2,}/gmi
```

See this [in action at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Pbp0M2/3)

### Explanation

This matches strings that suit the following criteria:

1. `^(?!.{36,})` It is not 36 characters or longer
2. `[a-z'-]{2,}` Starts with a word containing only "a" - "z", "'" and "-"
3. `\s` followed by a whitespace
4. `[a-z'-]{2,}` followed by a word like decribed in 2.

you should however specify the following flags: `gmi`:

1. `g` Get all matches, not just the first one
2. `m` Treats lines seperately
3. `i` Match without case-sensisitivity, since this was not a requirement and would have blown up the expression a bit ;)

Comment: 'Li d dfdf'  should match

Comment: This accepted answer does not work for "l ab ab" or "ab h abcd"

Comment: thats because it shouldn't match since l is less than two characters long and both phrases are have more that 2 "words".

Comment: You are wrong, two string must be of minimum 2 characters. For the rest it can be of any length

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(?=^[A-Za-z-' ]{1,35}$)(?=.*[a-z-']{2,}\s.*[a-z-']{2,}).*/gmi
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/lMSpe7/12)

1. **`(?=^[A-Za-z-' ]{1,35}$)`** positive look ahead to check length less than 36.
2. if matched then,
   **`(?=.*\w{2,}\s.*\w{2,})`** positive look ahead to check if two words exist having more than 2 chars.
3. if matched then, **`.*`** --> matches the entire string